# Socket.io Connection off with React Native Webview on Android

Tags: reactjs, webview, socket.io, native

I'm use React-native WebView

My application is using WebSocket communication in WebPage with socket.IO.
Websocket communication is automatically disconnected after a certain period of time.

Which part should I check? Is no problem when connecting from the web.
web application is implemented in React and Redux.

Thanks All.

Comment: Could you solve it? facing similar problem with socket.io connection breaking up after short amount of time in react-native webview